# Safety of sharing my apple password on screen with apple technician

Tags: ipad, apple-id, password

I recently had a problem with my apple id on my ipad. I called apple tech support and was guided through some steps by the technician.She assured me everything was ok but during the process I had to enter my apple id password 5 or 6 times whilst I was screen sharing with her.She said the internet signal kept dropping and she could not see what was going on.So I entered my password which was working correctly and the verification codes 5 or 6 times.
My initial problem was to do with changing my apple id password and tech was very helpful. I am sure that I called the correct apple support and I got a follow up email from apple.Question is is this usual apple says very clearly not to share password with anyone.

Comment: Did you give your plaintext password to the technician or did you enter it on an Apple.com website?

Answer (score 1):

Did you give your password to the tech, or type it into a browser?

If you typed it into a browser and the dots appeared, the tech cannot know what the password is.

It can't hurt to change your password again if you are concerned about anyone knowing it.